# Is this "gun stealing technique" realistic?

Tags: realism, the-equalizer

In the movie The Equalizer (2014) the protagonist manages to steal the gun a bad guy is pointing at him with a cool sleight of hand.

[image]

Does this move make any sense (is it a known technique?) or in real life it will probably result in the death of the protagonist?

Comment: As in pretty much everything, it would come down to who was faster - the guy grabbing the gun or the guy trying to pull the trigger...

Comment: @Dave I doubt that it's only a matter of being faster. Picking the gun in the wrong way could pull the trigger accidentally, even if the bad guy does nothing.

Answer (score 8):

It's a martial art technique to disarm your opponent.

From [wideopenspaces](http://www.wideopenspaces.com/worlds-fastest-gun-disarm-video/), Watch martial arts expert Victor Marx execute the world’s fastest gun disarm:

Even [wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Disarm-a-Criminal-with-a-Handgun) explains how to do it.

***Note: It's very risky move and in real life situation not everyone can execute it.***

Comment: I've also seen this technique demonstrated on an episode of the "Sons of Guns" TV show.

Comment: That's even more impressive than the movie's one. I'd mark you answer, except that I don't understand why you wrote "It's very risky move and in real life situation **everyone can't execute it**". I guess you meant "not everyone can execute it", right?

Comment: Yes, he used bad grammar to try to say "Not everyone can execute it".  If he meant "in real life situation everyone can't execute it" it would mean that the demonstration was staged and the trick would be totally impossible for even the most skilled martial artist to pull off against a real enemy.

Comment: One note about this: It's important to smack the inside of the wrist of the person with the gun, while simultaneously moving the gun the opposite direction. This lengthens the tendons in the fingers on the hand holding the gun, making it unlikely the fingers can contract to pull the trigger. But as described this is VERY difficult to do in real life and can lead to the gun going off.

Comment: @ReginaldKincaid updated

Answer (score 0):

It is; however it's practicality is questionable. Gun disarms are taught foolishly by modern day martial arts/self defense studios. The problem is the people who're taught it, seldom practice it. And the people who teach it.......have probably NEVER had to use it in their life.
But they're largely impractical.
It's overlooked by the rule of 3. If you're gonna hold someone at gunpoint, keep 3 feet away from them to keep them away from you. At three feet; that requires lunging at the armed assailant to even get your hands on the gun............A stupid thing to do.

A better strategy is to deflect the weapon's angle of approach by grabbing or push the barrel and attacking the opponents face/genitals. If they cant aim the weapon at you you're safer. Another safety tip, carry a fake wallet if you go out or if you live in a quesitonable area. Fill the wallet with two; one dollar bills sandwiched between some fake papers and some cardboard to simulate the thickness of cards. Someone tries to mug you give them the fake.